# How can I set sde object id from QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase

I have connected a geodatabse that was created by ArcGIS. My geometry type is `PG_GEOMETRY`. I can connect the database in QGIS and add a feature table as a layer. When I create new spatial data in this layer via QGIS, a data form appears. The form contains a text box for OBJECTID. But I can not know the next id. If I do not fill the OBJECTID box, it gives an error.

How can I set the next serial of the OBJECTID?

Comment: An OBJECTID is set by the geodatabase, you can't set it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have the solution. I have tried using the default value in QGIS to populate an OBJECTID field. Each new polygon then created using QGIS will receive the number of the feature that is created in QGIS. This feature should work even if there are pre-existing features in the feature class of the geodatabase.

[image]

In the image bellow, the two polygons bellow are created in ArcGIS, I then edit the Feature Class in QGIS, and assigined the $id property to the OBJECTID field.

[image]

I would additionally "hide" the ObjecID field from showing up in the edit dialog box.